# Usage about German 'bis'

Tags: grammar

1. *Wir gingen bis an den Rand des Abgrunds.* Can I delete *an* in this sentence? In German usually two prepositions stay together, which makes it a bit hard for me to understand.
2. *Bis auf den Kapitän wurden alle gerettet.* Can I delete *auf*?

Comment: "In German usually two prepositions stay together" - that isn't true. The phenomenon is specific to "bis", which isn't originally a true preposition; it is comparable to "*all the way* to the station". It's possible to delete the following preposition in *some* cases: "bis nach Frankfurt" -> "bis Frankfurt", and this gives the impression that "bis" was itself a preposition, but it's really more of an adverb in use.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You cannot remove the *an* in sentence number 1, because it implies that you went up to the edge of the abyss. You can also say :

*Wir gingen bis zum Rand Abgrunds.*

(2) Again, it is a "no" because if you remove the *auf*, the sentence will not make sense. The sentence is correct the way it is. There is another way to say it and it is :

*Außer dem Kapitän wurden alle gerettet.*

Answer (score 1):

### 1

You can not delete "an" but you can delete "bis":

> Wir gingen bis an den Rand des Abgrunds.
>   Wir gingen an den Rand des Abgrunds.

Both sentences have the same meaning.

The term "an den Rand des Abgrunds" expresses a movement towards a target, which means, that it is the answer to the question "wohin?" ("where to?"). Many languages (among them Hungarian) have a special case for this, which is named "allativ", but germanic languages (like English or German) don't have an allativ. Those languages use a modification of akkusativ to express a movement towards a target.

In English the correct answer to the question "where to" is not "the edge of the abyss". The correct answer ist "**to** the edge of the abyss".

Same in German: The answer to the question "wohin" is neither "der Rand des Abgrunds" nor "den Rand des Abgrunds". It is: "**an** den Rand des Abgrunds".

the word "bis" forces the allativ-like construction. If you omit "bis" this type of construction is one of many possible ways to continue the sentence:

> Wir gingen bis (*wohin*) **zum grünen Haus**
>
> Wir gingen (*wie*) **sehr schnell**
>   Wir gingen (*warum*) **weil wir nicht fahren wollten**
>   Wir gingen (*wie lange*) **schon 7 Stunden lang**
>   Wir gingen (*wohin*) **zum grünen Haus**

### 2

No, you can't omit "auf" because "bis auf" has a different meaning that has not much to do with the meaning of "bis" without "auf":

> **bis** = to, until, up to, till, by
>   **bis auf** = except for

So, *"bis auf" + Akkusativ* has the same meaning as *"außer" + Dativ*

Comment: "Wir gingen an den Rand" and "wir gingen bis an den Rand" don't have the same meaning. "Bis" makes the brink of the abyss the focus of attention: "Wir gingen bis an den Rand des Abgrunds, obwohl uns alle Einheimischen davor gewarnt hatten". Without "bis", the "Rand des Abgrunds" is one destination among others: "Wir gingen an den Rand des Abgrunds, dann besuchten wir das Wildschweingehege, bevor wir im Gasthaus einkehrten".